# Google Cast API - Is it possible to pass custom data on session request?

Tags: google-cast

When starting a session in the sender side and perform

```
chrome.cast.requestSession(...)
```

is it possible or there is any way to pass some custom object as an argument?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass information to the receiver using the [`LoadRequestData.customData`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager.LoadRequestData#customData) field, through the API's **load** method.

`cast.receiver.MediaManager.RequestData#customData`

Application-specific data for this request. It enables the sender and receiver to easily extend the media protocol without having to use a new namespace with custom messages.

For more information, use the Official Google Documentation: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver